# $_POST and WWWForm with bool.ToString() doesn't work

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have been working on making a custom server (probably won't work but I want to give it a try and work on it as a hobby) but I've already run into a problem! What I have the php scripts outputing the commands as text then getting unity to translate that into the c# commands.

Here's the ServerCalls.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class ServerCallsScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isPlayerInRoom = false;

    public bool autoConnectToLobby;
    public bool showLobbyGUI;

    public float width;
    public float height;
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public enum logTypeEnum {
        Developer,
        Debug,
        Warning,
        Error
    };
    public logTypeEnum logType = logTypeEnum.Warning;

    public string MainServerUrl = "https://network-hlapi-myusername.c9.io/serverMain.php";

    private string serverText = "";

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ServerCommands());
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showLobbyGUI)
        {
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(5,80,115,21), "Create Game"))
            {

            }
            GUI.TextField(new Rect(130, 80, 115, 21), "Game1");
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(5, 110, 115, 21), "Join Game"))
            {

            }
            GUI.TextField(new Rect(130, 110, 115, 21),"Game Name");
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// This is called as soon as the player opens the scene
    /// </summary>
    public void OnConnectedToServer()
    {
        if (logType == logTypeEnum.Debug || logType == logTypeEnum.Developer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully Connected To Server at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called When Player Connects To Lobby. Automatically called if auto-join lobby is enabled
    /// </summary>
    public void OnConnectedToLobby() {
        if (logType == logTypeEnum.Debug || logType == logTypeEnum.Developer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Connected To Lobby at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
    public void ShowLobbyGui() {
        if (logType == logTypeEnum.Debug || logType == logTypeEnum.Developer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Showing Lobby Gui");
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the player joins a game
    /// </summary>
    public void OnPlayerJoinedRoom()
    {
        if (logType == logTypeEnum.Debug || logType == logTypeEnum.Developer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Successfully Joined Room at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        }
    }



    IEnumerator ServerCommands() {
        Debug.Log("Collecting Info from Server...");
        WWWForm Mainform = new WWWForm();
        Mainform.AddField("isAutoJoinLobby", autoConnectToLobby.ToString());
        Mainform.AddField("isShowingLobbyGui", showLobbyGUI.ToString());
        Mainform.AddField("hasPlayerJoinedRoom", isPlayerInRoom.ToString());

        WWW mainServer = new WWW(MainServerUrl, Mainform);
        yield return mainServer;


        serverText = mainServer.text;
        string[] serverCommands = serverText.Split('\n');
        if(mainServer.error != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("We encountered an error! Error:" + mainServer.error);
        }
        if (serverCommands.Contains("OnConnectedToServer"))
        {
            OnConnectedToServer();
        }
        if (serverCommands.Contains("OnConnectedToLobby"))
        {
            Debug.Log("OnConnectedToLobby");
            OnConnectedToLobby();
        }
        if (serverCommands.Contains("showLobbyGui"))
        {
            ShowLobbyGui();
        }
        if (serverCommands.Contains("OnPlayerJoinedRoom"))
        {
            OnPlayerJoinedRoom();
        }

    }
}
```

For ServerMain.php:

```
<?php
    $servername = getenv('IP');
    $username = getenv('C9_USER');
    $password = "I Wouldn't Tell You That Now";
    $database = "server";
    $dbport = 3306;

    // Create connection
    $db = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbport)or die("Cant Connect to server");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Cant connect to database");

    $isAutoConnectToLobby = $_POST['isAutoJoinLobby'];
    $isShowingLobbyGui = $_POST['isShowingLobbyGui'];
    $hasPlayerJoinedRoom = $_POST['hasPlayerJoinedRoom'];
    $ClientClickConnectButton = $_POST['ClientClickConnectButton'];

    echo "OnConnectedToServer\n";
    if ($isAutoConnectToLobby == true){
        echo "OnConnectedToLobby\n";
    }
    if($isShowingLobbyGui == true){
        echo "showLobbyGui\n";
    }
    if($ClientClickConnectButton == true){
        sleep(5);      //Just to give some time to complete any in-complete operations
        echo "onClientClickConnectButton\n";
    }
    if($hasPlayerJoinedRoom == true){
        echo "OnPlayerJoinedRoom\n";
    }

?>
```

The problem is that the ServerMain.php script doesn't seem to listen to any of the WWWForm fields. If you add quotes to the if statements in the php script it just goes through all the if statements but if you don't add quotes it doesn't do any of the if statements, even if the public bools are enabled

Comment: Also, Please Don't Give me an answer saying "Your code's really messy! Clean it up!" or "You don't need this! It's of no use!". I know my code is really messy at the moment and could probably do with some cleaning up but I wanted to get this question out before I go to bed so I'd have an answer maybe by tomorrow

Comment: Can you test if the values are even set using isset?

Comment: Without looking at your code - have you tried Charles Proxy? Then you can see exactly what is being sent to the server.

Comment: @AdamJeffers changing the $_POST commands that should be returning true to isset() variables worked. Now I only send commands if the variable in unity is true. Mark your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() to first test if the value is available ;-)